# Powershell - Check binaries including Regex

Tags: powershell

I have a long script that test binaries. at the begging I get all the files, search if the folder contains number with exactly 7 digits and for each file I check if the name have exactly 7 digits.
If the file don't have 7 digits and the folder have, I rename the file with the folder number.
If the file is valid the script continue.
If both don't have a number the script continue to the next file.

I have a lot of issues with the regex.
First when the folder name contains 7 digits with '' at the end I don't have result

```
C:\Users\3D Objects\Patch Managment\1399771\
```

The 7 digits can be Everywhere in the path

As you can see I am using $file.BaseName because the regex is not working if there is an extension.
File can be:

```
patch-8.6.22 (1399771-Increase timeout).zip
Patch-1234567.vip
Patch_1234567.zip
```

If the file have any sign after the 7 digits its also not working.
It is very important to find only 7 digit!! if the is more or less the result should be Null
Please try to help me to change the regex and maybe I missed any logical (I am not sure if the if and elseif --> else will give me all the option I mentioned)

```
$FilesPath = Read-Host -Prompt ""
if ($FilesPath -match '\D(\d{7})$') {
$FolderNumber = $Matches[1]
}
$compressedfiles = Get-ChildItem -path $FilesPath\* -Include "*.vip", "*.zip", "*.cab"
foreach ($file in $compressedfiles) {
        $validNumber = 'False'
        
        if (($file.Name -notmatch '\D(\d{7})$' -and $FolderNumber -eq ""))  {
            Write-Verbose -Verbose "Skipping $($file.Name) due to a wrong format or invalid folder name, file name should contains 7 digits or a valid folder name which represents a valid patch number (7 digits)"
            Write-Log -Level ERROR -logfile $loglocation -Message "Skipping $($file.Name) due to a wrong format or invalid folder name, file name should contains 7 digits or a valid folder name which represents a valid patch number (7 digits)"
            continue
        }
        elseif (($file.BaseName -notmatch '\D(\d{7})$') -and $FolderNumber -ne "") {
            RenameFile
        }
        else {
           $validNumber = 'True'
        } 
if ($validNumber -eq 'True') {
            Try {
                $MatcheddllFiles = @()
                $PatchNumber = ""
                $PatchBranch = ""
                $Customername = ""
                $CustomerTosearch = "JSOC"
                $patchNumber = $Matches[1]
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to put the 7 digits? Beginning or end of BaseName?

Comment: It could be at the end and at the beginning...
Basically for most of the cases there is only 1 number of 7 digits
Something with the regex is not right especially for folder...when there is a \ after the number

Comment: Keep it simple :  "[^\d]\d{7}[^\d]"